# JAVA Quartz - Skip job if previous is still running AND wait for the next schedule time

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a Java solution that uses `Quartz 2.2.3`, and what I have is:

- My job class is annotated `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` to avoid concurrence, so the same job just can run once per time (OK)
- It is a CRON and runs every 1 hour (OK)
- The time is 1pm and the the job starts run (OK)
- Now the time is 2pm and the previous job didn't finish yet (OK)
- As the class is annotated the next job will not start (IT IS GREAT - OK)
- Now the time is 2h:15min and the first job just finished (OK)
- Now the issue, as the second job didn't start at 2pm BUT now the first just finished, the second one will start.

This is my problem, I don't want to make the second job wait if the previous didn't finish, I want to skip the second one and when the time turns `3pm` the job can run. Reading javadoc I added the `withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()` but it didn't work.

I think I'm doing something wrong or missing something.

My code:

```
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TestCronService.class).withIdentity("testA","testB").build();


CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("testA","testB")
.withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 * * * ?")
.withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
.build();


scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
scheduler.start();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to skip cron trigger firetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155665/how-to-skip-cron-trigger-firetime)

Answer (score 7):

Change the function :

```
withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()
```

with

```
withMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount()
```

Comment: This is the answer, read more: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html